# Spark 3.2.1 Installation Error starts with java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: apache-spark

I have tried to install the latest Spark 3.2.1 version in my local I have Java, scala as below. Also used the Hadoop 3.2 winutils in c:\hadoop\bin but the 'spark-shell' shows the below error

But when I am using Spark 3.1.2 it is working fine.

Answers are welcomed

```
java version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
Using Scala version 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_202-release)
```

**ERROR:**

```
C:\Users\******>spark-shell
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/01/29 14:52:06 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/01/29 14:52:12 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.addReplClassLoaderIfNeeded(Executor.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:220)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2690)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:949)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:747)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1020)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:568)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:116)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:567)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:594)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:564)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$quietRun$1(IMain.scala:216)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:206)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietRun(IMain.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$initializeSpark$2(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$initializeSpark$1(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$4(SparkILoop.scala:165)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.$anonfun$mumly$1(ILoop.scala:166)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:206)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.mumly(ILoop.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loopPostInit$1(SparkILoop.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$10(SparkILoop.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.withSuppressedSettings$1(SparkILoop.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.startup$1(SparkILoop.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:955)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 32: spark://LAPTOP-KLU8JAI8:62255/C:\classes
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.<init>(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
        ... 70 more
22/01/29 14:52:12 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.org$apache$spark$scheduler$local$LocalSchedulerBackend$$stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.stop(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:2567)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$stop$12(SparkContext.scala:2086)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1442)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:2086)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:677)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2690)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:949)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:747)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1020)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:568)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:116)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:567)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:594)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:564)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$quietRun$1(IMain.scala:216)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:206)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietRun(IMain.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$initializeSpark$2(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$initializeSpark$1(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$4(SparkILoop.scala:165)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.$anonfun$mumly$1(ILoop.scala:166)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:206)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.mumly(ILoop.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loopPostInit$1(SparkILoop.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$10(SparkILoop.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.withSuppressedSettings$1(SparkILoop.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.startup$1(SparkILoop.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:955)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
22/01/29 14:52:12 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
22/01/29 14:52:12 ERROR Main: Failed to initialize Spark session.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.addReplClassLoaderIfNeeded(Executor.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:220)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2690)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:949)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:747)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1020)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:568)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:116)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:567)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:594)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:564)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$quietRun$1(IMain.scala:216)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:206)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.quietRun(IMain.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$initializeSpark$2(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$initializeSpark$1(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$4(SparkILoop.scala:165)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.$anonfun$mumly$1(ILoop.scala:166)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:206)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.mumly(ILoop.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loopPostInit$1(SparkILoop.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$10(SparkILoop.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.withSuppressedSettings$1(SparkILoop.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.startup$1(SparkILoop.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:955)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 32: spark://LAPTOP-KLU8JAI8:62255/C:\classes
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.<init>(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:57)
        ... 70 more
22/01/29 14:52:12 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread shutdown-hook-0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.stop(Executor.scala:333)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$stopHookReference$1(Executor.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2019)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$1(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleBlockPusher$.<init>(ShuffleBlockPusher.scala:465)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleBlockPusher$.<clinit>(ShuffleBlockPusher.scala)
        ... 16 more
22/01/29 14:52:12 WARN ShutdownHookManager: ShutdownHook '$anon$2' failed, java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.executeShutdown(ShutdownHookManager.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.stop(Executor.scala:333)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$stopHookReference$1(Executor.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2019)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$1(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleBlockPusher$.<init>(ShuffleBlockPusher.scala:465)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleBlockPusher$.<clinit>(ShuffleBlockPusher.scala)
        ... 16 more
```

The above error occured and I have tried with different Hadoop winutils versions also but issue persists

Comment: Have you tried running it on Java 11 or 8?

Comment: check logs I see Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 32: spark://LAPTOP-KLU8JAI8:62255/C:\classes
You are providing spark master uri in wrong format.

Comment: @ernest_k will check in that

Comment: @AmitKumar Thanks for the reply but i haven't changed any code it is default code downloaded from the repo

Comment: @ernest_k Java 16 is forward compatible right? I am not a JAVA developer but if it works in 11 has to work in 16 also right?

Comment: Can you add repo link, if it is public.